# TypeScript list iteration inside return statement

Tags: typescript, iteration, react-typescript, tsx

I am new at React-TypeScript and want to make a visual list of Publisher type of objects which should look like this:
[the screenshot of my javascript code which can list my objects properly inside return statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmSvy.png)

This is my return statement which is coded using TypeScript but does not working. It does not give any error but gives full white screen.

```
return (
        <div>
        <input type="text" placeholder='Name' className='input_box' onChange={(i) => searchFor(i)} />
            <div className="container" >
                {publishers.map((publisher:Publisher) =>
                    <Card border="secondary" style={{ width: '18rem',  maxWidth: 'auto', height: 'auto',  maxHeight: 'auto', margin: 15, background: 'linear-gradient(45deg, #FE6B8B 30%, #FF8E53 90%)' }}>
                        <Card.Img style={{ width: "auto", maxHeight: "200px", padding: '5px' }} variant="top" src={img}/>
                        <Card.Body>
                            <Card.Title key="{publisher_name}">{publisher.name}</Card.Title>
                            <ListGroup variant="flush" style={{ listStyle: 'none'}}>
                                <ListGroup.Item key="{website}">{publisher.website}</ListGroup.Item>
                                <ListGroup.Item key="{phone}">{publisher.phone}</ListGroup.Item>
                                <ListGroup.Item key="{address}">{publisher.address}</ListGroup.Item>
                            </ListGroup>
                        </Card.Body>
                    </Card>  
                    )
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    );
```

I am pretty sure that `publishers` is not empty because I tried this kind of code in javascript file and took the screenshot above. Can you please help me how can I list my objects inside this `return` statement? I also tried foreach but it also was not successfull.

Note: You may need to see my Publisher class. Here it is:

```
export class Publisher {
    name: string = "";
    website: string = "";
    phone: string = "";
    address: string = "";
  
    constructor(initializer?: any) {
      if (!initializer) return;
      if (initializer.name) this.name = initializer.name;
      if (initializer.website) this.website = initializer.website;
      if (initializer.phone) this.phone = initializer.phone;
      if (initializer.address) this.address = initializer.address;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, even when you watch in the console there isn't any error ?

Comment: I had already wrote about it, but lost. It gives Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') error.

Comment: Here is how I solve this problem:

```
 {publishers.map((publisher: Publisher) => (
  <div>
     <p>{publisher.website}</p>
  </div>
 ))}
```
I added extra parenthesis after '=>' symbol.